# jQuery On Not working for simple script

Tags: javascript, jquery

There must be some mental block that I'm just not getting...My entire site is working fine, but dynamically created links with an ID are not. Something is wrong in my code...it's as simple as this but it's not working, please show me my dumb mistake (I know it's something simple).

so for example this would be a generated link:

```
<a href="#" id="himan">Hi</a>
```

and then I have this script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click','#himan',function(){
 alert('hi');
});
});
```

but nothing happens, and I get no errors...I'm lost, maybe my coffee is not working today. Can someone help me?

Comment: is jQuery included on the page?

Comment: What is your version of jQuery? Because it is working : http://jsfiddle.net/Nz2V9/

Comment: Try: $('#himan').on('click', function() { ... });

Comment: Are there any errors? Did you load jQuery first? By the way, the `$(document).ready` wrapper is [unnecessary](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/Nz2V9/1/) in this case.

Comment: By "I get no errors", you confirm you opened the console and you've put a breakpoint ?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the id himan? Are you sure the id is correct?

Comment: @DanielAttfield he bound to document because it's dynamically created. OP probably have more than one of these with the same ID.. maybe

Comment: Given the element is dynamically created, isn't the binding of events to it occur more appropriate after creation anyway? How is the element created?

Comment: I bet that jQuery is not loaded...

Comment: @DanielAttfield It is personal preference when you add it. There is no right or wrong way.

Comment: @DanielAttfield what I mean is the elements could be created due to user interaction or sometime after the doc is ready. Which would indicate a reason to bind the event to the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/ghryP/)

It is working perfect:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '#himan', function () {
         alert('hi');
     });
 });
```

reason might be duplicate of id, there must only one element with specific id because id is a unique on a page, if you adding multiple element use class instead of id.

Comment: Even though you are right about duplicating ID's, using delegation will not "block" the code and still work : http://jsfiddle.net/Nz2V9/2/

Comment: also the class thing ended up for cleaner execution, i knew this, but forgot, thanks!!!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `click` event on `#himan` itself...

```
function initializeDynamicLinks() {
    $('#himan').on('click',function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    initializeDynamicLinks()
});
```

Here you see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/emUWL/

Rerun `initializeDynamicLinks()` whenever you add links dynamically.

**And...** as has been pointed out several times in comments, you need to make sure `#himan` only occurs once in your source to be completely sure everything will function properly.

Comment: No you do not need it on the element itself.

Comment: probably will not work since the anchor is dynamically created, if you put his code in a fiddle it will work as well

Comment: @Huangism that would be guessing, not really helping at all. the question shows its not created after document.ready

Comment: Either way, I edited my answer to handle both cases.

Comment: Do you not understand what event bubbling is? There is *NO* need to add the event directly!

Comment: @GertB. I am not guessing, the anchor is created dynamically. if you read the question "My entire site is working fine, but dynamically created links with an ID are not." either way, OP's code should work and your code does not solve the issue at hand

Comment: @Huangism I'm sorry, my mistake. that would indeed explain the problem.